# creating record via command line in Rails - not sure about this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to create a tag via:

```
[14] pry(main)> Tag.create! {"phrase" => "here is my phrase" }
SyntaxError: unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}'
Tag.create! {"phrase" => "here is my phrase" }
                        ^
[14] pry(main)> d = {"phrase" => "here is my phrase"}
=> {"phrase"=>"here is my phrase"}
[15] pry(main)> Tag.create! d                        ^
```

I don't know what's wrong but I can't get this to work. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

thx

Answer (score 0):

actually you forgot the bracket
try

> Tag.create!({"phrase" => "here is my phrase" })

Comment: yeah, looks reasonable too but I think it needs to be as an arg and NOT as a hash. I'm really surprised by this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

Tag.create{:phrase => "here is my phrase"}

Comment: I think it needs to be as a params and NOT as a hash. Would have thought this would work though.